# Nested children nodes in navigation tree inherit link tag from their parent node

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a navigation menu with nested unordered lists based on JSON data and no matter which approach I take (array.map / for-loops / self-invoking functions and explicit code for every nested level) somehow a parent  tag gets inserted in the nested list when I add  tags for the child elements. Like this:

```
<ul> // works fine!
  <li><a href="/lvl0-item">Lvl0 Item</a>
    <ul>
      <li>Lvl1 Item A</li>
      <li>Lvl1 Item B</li>
      <li>Lvl1 Item C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul> // gives me headaches!
  <li><a href=/lvl0item">Lvl0 Item</a>
    <ul>
      <a href=/lvl0item"></a> <-- where is this coming from?
      <li><a href="/lvl1item-a">Lvl1 Item A</li>
      <li><a href="/lvl1item-b">Lvl1 Item B</li>
      <li><a href="/lvl1item-c">Lvl1 Item C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

Here's my latest and desperate render function:

```
function TreeNodes (dataset) {
  var createNodes = dataset.map( function(node) {
    let listObjs = {};

    var subLvlNode = function(listitems) {
      for(let i = 0; i < listitems.length; i++) {
        listObjs[i] = (<li key={listitems[i].id}><a>{listitems[i].title}</a></li>);
      }
      return listObjs;
    };

    if(node.hasOwnProperty('children')) {
      node.lvl1Children = (<ul>{subLvlNode(node.children)}</ul>);
    } else {
      node.lvl1Children = null;
    }

    return (
      <li key={node.id} data-navimg=""><a href={node.href}>{node.title}{node.lvl1Children}</a></li>
    );
  });

  return createNodes;
}

return (
  <nav>
    <ul className="navbar-default">
      {TreeNodes(navNodes.menu)}
    </ul>
  </nav>
);
```

---

Data structure:

```
navNodes: { "menu" : [
  { "id": 0, "title": "BAM", "href": "bam/", "children": [
    { "id": "sf", "title": "BAMKID 1", "href": "bamkid1/" },
    { "id": "fsf", "title": "BAMKID 2", "href": "bamkid2/"},
    { "id": "umd", "title": "BAMKID 3", "href": "bamkid3/"}
  ]}
]}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/wiredprairie/bg4y9rr7/

Comment: Thanks for providing the jsfiddle - never thought about that. But even there the problem occurs. A DevTools inspections reveals the additional <a> tag in the child list as well.

Note: I edited the post above a slight bit. The unintended <a> tag does not come with link text, so it's generally not shown.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted out on Github -  tags are officially not allowed within  tags. Closing the parent  tag before including the child list solves the problem.